# Increment ID number by 1 in Excel and repeat the incremented number 2 times

Tags: vba, excel, increment

I just started to learn Excel VBA so bear with me here, I have a column of ID numbers and I already figured out how to generate numbers from 1 to the end of a list as follow 1,2,3,4 etc.

The problem is how can I generate a list of ID numbers like this 1,1,2,2,3,3 etc  (row 1 and row 2 should have the same incremented number)

Here is what I did to increment numbers by 1 :

```
Sub AddingNbr()
Columns("A").Insert
Range("A1").Value = "ID"
 For i = 1 To Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = i
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Sub AddingNbr()
Columns("A").Insert copyorigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
Range("A1").Value = "ID"
 For i = 1 To Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(CDec(i) / CDec(2), 1)
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code somehow doesn't run and highlights CEILING with error sub or function not defined. EDIT: i just saw your second comment and changed Ceiling the code works thanks a lot you are a Genius !

Answer (score -1):

well all this is fine, but I have a nice way to do incrementation of values in excel with the one format we want. This formula really helps espacially when you want to use forms. That's the formula:
`="LIVR"&TEXT(IF(A1=$A$1;0;MID(A1;5;3)+1);"000")` it makes that

```
LIVR000
LIVR001
LIVR002
LIVR003
...
LIVR999
```